# Exporting data (users) into another location?

Tags: export

is there a way to automatically export a file (with contacts information) outside of the CiviCRM installation to another location?

I'm using CiviCRM on Drupal and before looking at Drupal's side, I'm wondering if this is possible with CiviCRM.

I want to connect to a Wordpress site to create users.

Any experience?

Comment: you could also consider some form of single-sign-on such as simplesaml but that may be jumping in much deeper than required

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Drupal + views, and can include all the necessary fields of the contact.

From Civi you can use Civi reports and download them as csv using `reset=1&output=csv&force=1` in url.

Could also use getrows for reporttemplate entity rest api

You may need to check with user permission on both the options.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: very good Pradeep! This is one step forward. Thanks